# can I do .load from a url with query string?

Tags: jquery, load

I'm not all the familiar with the .load functionality of jQuery, but it would be REALLY cool if I could do what's in the url.

Basically, I've got a PHP loop that cycles for 10 pieces of content per page. This is based on a Query String

`http://domain.com/page/?offSet=0&rpp=10`

will load the 10 most recent bits of content (rpp=10)

`http://domain.com/page/?offSet=10&rpp=10`

this loads the content 11-20 (notice offset=10). Offset 20 will produce 21-30, etc.

BASICALLY - I've got some links at the bottom that use PHP math to determine the current offset and add 10  or subtract 10.

Currently, they reload the whole page (gross). Can I use .load with the query strings to grab the container div with the other content?

Comment: yes.... you can?

P.S. you should always try first before you ask... Just sayin

Comment: This is called pagination (or paging). Makes sense to return from the *server* just the number of results to display. Otherwise, download all as data and show only what you want (no secondary `$.load()` calls, though) on page "request".

Comment: Someone upvoted this - they might have wondered too. I didn't want to get too far into coding it just to realize it didn't work (every example I could find referenced an extensioned address `domain.com/page.aspx` etc. with no query string to boot. Figured I'd ask for those who want to know but don't know and spend all day on SO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do that.  You can add a selector after your URL to indicate only what section of the loaded HTML that you want to insert into your current page's container.

For example:

```
$('#myGridOfData').load('/page/?offSet=10&rpp=10 #container');
```

Which will load only the contents of `#container` from your loaded resource into `#myGridData`.

See the jQuery [API](http://api.jquery.com/load/) for more details.